# Reducing Process Core in CentOS

Tags: operating-system, centos, processor

I need to reduce my Corei7 processor to single core.
Searching forums i came to know about how to do it using `BIOS` or in `Windows`.

But is there a way to limit the processor number in `CentOS` (As my BIOS doesn't have any such options)? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Even with precision laser cutting or a diamond saw, I suspect this will be very difficult.

Comment: I wonder if you really need it, or just *think* you need, because you have layers of bad "solutions" already in place.

Comment: @Griwes - yeah, that...

Answer (score 2):

Run it in a VM with only one core assigned to it.